# ArgumentError in Users#show Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arguments

I keep getting the above error and the following message:

```
'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.
```

The error points to the source as line 18.

```
15:     <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
16:       <h3>Comments (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
17:       <ol class="microposts">
18:         <%= render @microposts %>
19:       </ol>
20:       <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
21:     <% end %>
```

I tried checking the naming conventions but I took them exactly as shown in a rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. I have a similar chunk of code for a model called "recipes" so I'm assuming I will get a similar error with that too. The weird thing is that I can create both microposts and recipes and both will show on the home page for the signed_in user. I am getting this error when I go to "Users" and try to click on the accounts there. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: from which html page is the code? micropost's index?

Comment: The code is from the "show.html.erb" file

Comment: but the micropost controller?

Comment: Oh yes the micropost controller

Answer (score 2):

The failing line is attempting to render a partial view -- the argument to render, `@microposts` is `nil` but is usually a string that references a view file, for example

```
<%= render "microposts" %>
```

would tell rails to look for a file named `_microposts.html.erb` in the `views/users` directory.  The use of `render` in a view is different than in a controller.

[See doc on rendering partials here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

P.S.  Welcome to StackOverflow -- nice first question!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, while other answer is informative, this underlying problem has more to do with a discrepancy in the tutorial. It instructs you to add this code to your users_controller:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

but earlier in the tutorial you have this #show method that I didn't recall and I ended up having two #show methods in my controller upon adding the one from chapter 13:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
  end
```

..so what I did to resolve this is combined them into one method and then I got the user page with the unstyled microposts like in the tutorial figure. Not entirely sure how to refer this Hartl but I figured I would add this here as I am also just starting Rails, ran into this issue for about 20 frustrating minutes and somehow noticed the duplicate method after scanning my user_controller for some reason.

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
  end
```